# Suggest download filename asynchronously in Chrome Ext

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm writing my first simple Chrome extension which should organize downloads into subfolders based on the title of the tab they're downloaded from. I'm planning on extending this in future, but for the time being I can't even get this simple functionality to work. The problem seems to be that the 'filename suggest' function cannot be called from within the asynchronous tab query. Code below is the full contents of the background JavaScript file:

```
chrome.downloads.onDeterminingFilename.addListener(function (item, __suggest) {

    //Find active tab
    chrome.tabs.query({ active: true }, function (tabs) {
        var activeTab = tabs[0];

        //Generate filepath
        var filepath = activeTab.title + "/" + item.filename;

        //TODO: Sanitize filepath.

        //Suggest filename for this download.
        __suggest({ filename: filepath });
    })

});
```

The error logged by the console is:

```
suggestCallback may not be called more than once. (extensions::downloads:42)
```

I've checked that the suggest function (in my JS) is definitely only called once. Any ideas how I can fix/work around this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As [the documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/downloads#event-onDeterminingFilename) says:

> If the listener calls `suggest` asynchronously, then it must return `true`.

So you need to add `return true` after your call to `chrome.tabs.query`.

Comment: Ah, missed that bit. Thanks a lot.